# jquery fullcalendar event with handler asp.net c#

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, handler

I am using jquery fullcalendar in my asp.net application.
pls see code-
ASPX code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            events: "SchedulerJsonResponse.ashx",
            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                            '(should probably update your database)');
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
```

SchedulerJsonResponse.ashx-

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        string res = scheduleTest.getAllScheduledSessionsOfLocation();

        context.Response.Write(res);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.Close();
    }
```

In above code `scheduleTest.getAllScheduledSessionsOfLocation()` method returns foll. string to handler -

```
[{title: 'Puneet sdfsdfsdf',allDay:false,start:  '02/20/2012 1:30:00 PM',end: '02/20/2012 2:00:00 PM'},{title: 'abc xyz',allDay:false,start:  '03/05/2012 6:00:00 AM',end: '03/05/2012 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '03/07/2012 7:30:00 PM',end: '03/07/2012 7:30:00 PM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '03/12/2012 2:00:00 PM',end: '03/12/2012 2:00:00 PM'},{title: 'abc xyz',allDay:false,start:  '03/12/2012 6:00:00 AM',end: '03/12/2012 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '03/14/2012 7:30:00 PM',end: '03/14/2012 7:30:00 PM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '03/19/2012 2:00:00 PM',end: '03/19/2012 2:00:00 PM'},{title: 'abc xyz',allDay:false,start:  '03/19/2012 6:00:00 AM',end: '03/19/2012 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '03/21/2012 7:30:00 PM',end: '03/21/2012 7:30:00 PM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '03/26/2012 2:00:00 PM',end: '03/26/2012 2:00:00 PM'},{title: 'abc xyz',allDay:false,start:  '03/26/2012 6:00:00 AM',end: '03/26/2012 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '03/28/2012 7:30:00 PM',end: '03/28/2012 7:30:00 PM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '04/02/2012 2:00:00 PM',end: '04/02/2012 2:00:00 PM'},{title: 'abc xyz',allDay:false,start:  '04/02/2012 6:00:00 AM',end: '04/02/2012 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '04/04/2012 7:30:00 PM',end: '04/04/2012 7:30:00 PM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '04/09/2012 2:00:00 PM',end: '04/09/2012 2:00:00 PM'},{title: 'abc xyz',allDay:false,start:  '04/09/2012 6:00:00 AM',end: '04/09/2012 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '04/11/2012 7:30:00 PM',end: '04/11/2012 7:30:00 PM'},{title: 'bhuvana ',allDay:false,start:  '04/16/2012 2:00:00 PM',end: '04/16/2012 2:00:00 PM'},{title: 'abc xyz',allDay:false,start:  '04/16/2012 6:00:00 AM',end: '04/16/2012 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '03/24/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '03/24/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '03/31/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '03/31/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '04/07/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '04/07/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '04/14/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '04/14/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '04/21/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '04/21/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '04/28/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '04/28/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '05/05/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '05/05/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '05/12/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '05/12/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '05/19/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '05/19/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '05/26/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '05/26/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '06/02/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '06/02/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '06/09/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '06/09/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '06/16/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '06/16/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '06/23/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '06/23/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '06/30/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '06/30/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '07/07/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '07/07/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '07/14/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '07/14/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '07/21/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '07/21/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '07/28/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '07/28/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '08/04/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '08/04/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '08/11/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '08/11/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '08/18/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '08/18/2014 6:00:00 AM'},{title: 'rtew ',allDay:false,start:  '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM',end: '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM'}]
```

But In calendar it is not showing any event. I hardcoded response in fullcalenders event then its working fine.
Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Abhi you need to have double quotes around both key and value pairs... e.g.

[{"title":"Puneet sdfsdfsdf","allDay":false,"start":"02/20/2012 1:30:00 PM","end":"02/20/2012 2:00:00 PM"},.... etc

As all your events have both start and end dates you could use allDayDefault:false and not include "allDay":false in json feed.

Also I had problems with some datetime formats where in some browsers events would show in others using the same feed the events did not show. I ended up using "2012-02-20T13:30:00+000" which worked with all browsers I tested.